# How can I put series of numbers to a list in android?

Tags: android

What I'm trying to is making a list which contains series of numbers like [1,2,3,4,5,6...100].

In Java, it is simple using 'range' so I tried to find similar class in android.

Therefore, I found that some classes like Range and Intstream, but I don't know how to use them.

I'll be appreciated if you teach me how can I get my purpose, thanks.

Comment: Android is mainly written in java, why would you need to do it differently if you know how to do it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple function which would look like this:

```
public List<Integer> buildList(int maximum) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 1; i <= maximum; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    return list;
}
```

And a call which produces your desired result would look like this:

```
List<Integer> list = buildList(100);
```

If you want an array instead of a list, do this:

```
int[] array = list.toArray(new int[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int size = 100;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(size);
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            Log.i("Value is = ", i+"");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
.....
```

You don't need to define the size because ArrayList is dynamically

while in some other language we use **list[index]** to get the value.
But here we use **list.get(index)** to do that.